# Does Flurry Reporting API show retention in country-dimension?

Tags: api, reporting, flurry, flurry-analytics

So flurry has provided its reporting API tool, however only with this rollingrate and returnrate, however when we trying to grab metrics for specific region, it's unable to achieve. Does flurry officially support the country-dimension reporting API function? or is there any way to achieve this.
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/code/analyticsapi/retention/

Answer (score 0):

The retention API does not officially support the country dimension. If you use the Retention Dashboard in Explorer, you can use User Country as a Breakout, then download the csv file.